# Read first row from csv file and create table according to it(csv file fields)

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Read first row from csv file and create table automatically according to  it(csv file fields) in mysql. Looking for PHP script?
 I have tried this

```
 <?php

$arr = array(array(),array());
$num = 0;
$row = 0;
$handle = fopen("./contacts.csv", "r");


while($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")){   
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $arr[$row][$c] = $data[$c];
    }
    $row++;
}


$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("excel_database",$con);

for($i=1; $i<$row; $i++){
$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts VALUES ('".$arr[$i][0]."','".$arr[$i][1]."','".$arr[$i][2]."','".$arr[$i][3]."','".$arr[$i][4]."','".$arr[$i][5]."')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
}

?>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @reza..problem in creating the table... if i already create the table the data is been imported. But iam looking something to create the table automatically with the cvs file fields.

Comment: What seems to be the problem with CREATE TABLE?

Comment: @manuell.. create table with fields from excel file automatically. Creating a table directly is not a problem but i am looking for script which reads excel file and creates the table according to its header field. Thank You

Comment: try this link [link](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/470490/read-first-row-from-csv-file-and-create-table-according-to-csv-file-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is half way to your question.

```
<?php
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("ab.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";

            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

whith `array_shift(file('filename.csv'))` will give you the first line of the document `filename.csv`

Comment: you are right, i had a mistake, now i changed `file_get_contents` to `file`, 
this one should work

Answer (score 4):

Modifiying your script a bit, this should do the trick and create the table according to the csv header line:

```
    $sql[] = array();
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");

    $header = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",");
    if($header){
        $header_sql = array();
        foreach($header as $h){
            $header_sql[] = '`'.$h.'` VARCHAR(255)';
        }
        $sql[] = 'CREATE TABLE `imported_csv` ('.implode(',',$header_sql).')';

        while($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")){   
            $sql[] = "INSERT INTO imported_csv VALUES ('".implode("','",$data)."')";
        }
    }        

    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db("excel_database",$con);
    foreach($sql as $s){
        mysql_query($s,$con);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a *single function* to give you an array: [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/fgetcsv) See Example #1 on that page for a basic script.

The table will just be a matter of looping over the contents ...

Aha, I finally parsed "table automatically according to it in mysql" and understood. Sorry. fgetcsv will return an array; just use that array to create your sql command. e.g. `'...values (' . implode(',', $results_of_fgetcsv) . ')...'`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to visualize the table data, in html, you can create a table using PHP and data from csv reading the first line as headers. I use this function that you can try it!

```
function build_table($source){
$data = array();
$file = fopen($source, 'r');
while (($result = fgetcsv($file,0,";")) !== false){$data[] = $result;}
fclose($file);


//Now process the data and create table
$data_rows=@count($data[0]); //from the first row get the header name
$colum_trail="";
//Create the header part
for($i=0; $i<$data_rows;$i++){
$cell=$data[0][$i]; //each header
$colum_trail.="<th>$cell</th>";    
}

////Create the table body contents     
$table_cells="";

for($i=1; $i<count($data);$i++){
$table_cells.="<tr>";       
$cell=$data[$i];

foreach($cell as $cell_value){
$cell_v=$cell_value;
$table_cells.="<td>$cell_v</td>";
}
$table_cells.="</tr>";
}

$table="<table><tr>$colum_trail</tr>$table_cells</table>";
echo "<style>td {border-bottom: 2px solid black;}</style>";
echo $table;
}
```

Then all you need is to after that code, call that function like this:

```
build_table("source.csv");  //then call the file you want to create table
```